# Android 4.2.2 Screen Capture on Galaxy Tab 2 10.1

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, screenshots, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1

I've browsed for  this information and everything I've found says to hit the power button and  volume down at the same time and a white line appears around the screen and you have a capture.

I've tried so many times and i just can't do this.

I can get blank the screen
I can make the Power Off, Flight Mode, Restart dialog appear
I can get the volume slider to appear
I can even get the volume slider to appear and power off dialog to appear at the same time.

I've tried pressing both together, pressing one and then the other, Holding one down and pressing the other, holding both down. I even tried pushing my tab against the desk, edge on, to flatten both buttons at the same time.

And after 30 minutes I still can't seen to get any screenshots, but I have rebooted twice.

Is there some that works on voice or shake or hold on screen that would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works out that you just have to keep trying. The Power and Volume down together (for around a second) will eventually yield a screenshot about 1 time out of a hundred. Took a look at most of the apps out there and they either need you to root the device or install loads of other stuff, work for phones rather than tablets or just don't work.

Guess I'm stuck with the crazy combination!

Comment: [by anonymous] All you do is press the power button a split second before the volume button and holding both down for 2 seconds until you see the white outline. Works every time.

Answer (score 0):

I own the Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 and that isn't the way to do a screen capture. Holding the power button with the volume buttons cause the Galaxy Tab to reset.  On my model (there may be other models that may have a different location for these buttons....my reference book shows the buttons on the lower right) the Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 has 4 buttons on the left bottom of the screen.  The curved arrow is the back button. The house is the home button  The two rectangles are the recent apps button. The fourth button is a rectangle with a cross - that is the screen capture button...just press it.

Comment: Yes, this incredibly easy way to get a screen capture was what I'd previously used - but since Samsung pushed Jelly Bean 4.2.2 and I updated that forth icon is no longer there and my  frustration and reason for me asking the question.

Comment: Ah....thought you just didn't know how to take a screenshot.  Yes, i have heard the same thing - that the update to Jellybean 4.2 removed the screenshot button.  From what I understand, you need to hit the power button and the volume down button AT THE SAME TIME.

Answer (score 0):

Press and hold the power button and volume-down button at the same time. It works.

Comment: like I said - it only works every now and again for me. Its a poor design that removing and easier / friendlier way of doing it from the device is a big fail.

Comment: The buttons must be pressed for as long as 2 or 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for my English :) 
I had the same problem! And I did everything you did and nothing! But 1 minute ago I just press the power button and volume down at the same time for 2 sec and a white line appeared!!! around the screen and I had a capture! It's really hard to do! 
Just try once more! Good luck! :)